# Jquery val() always returns first value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to identify a comment from multiple comments using a referenceId when someone clicks reply. But jquery keeps returning just the first value "f8ea3021-03d6-4099-8cc0-a3d9be7cd3be". Been trying since yesterday without success.

part of html:

```
    <div class="media" th:each="comment,iterStats : ${comments}">
            <input class="commentReferenceId" type="hidden" th:name="commentReferenceId" th:value="${comment.commentReferenceId}">
        
//snippet but within .media class
            <li class="comment_like">
               <a class="reply" href="#">
                   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
                     Reply
               </a>
            </li>
```

Structure:
[image]

Jquery:

```
  $('.reply').on('click', function() {

        var commentReferenceId = $('.commentReferenceId').val();
        console.log("commentReferenceId = " + commentReferenceId);
  });
```

Expected value:
On click should only return the commentReferenceId for that particular comment where the click was made. So .reply class is present in every media object

Comment: So what is expected behavior? You can only get value of one input at a time. When you have a jQuery collection of elements almost all of the getter methods will get from the first in the collection but you can use loop methods like `$.each` or `map()` or `filter()` to isolate instances

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why not just review what the doc says?  https://api.jquery.com/val/ *Get the current value **of the first element** in the set of matched elements*

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @freedomn-m, I believe you have a right to your own comment but to say I did not do research is not correct. I usually do not post unless I am stuck and there is no shame in that

Comment: @CODI "xxx function doesn't do what *you* think it should do" ... documentation clearly states it does what it does correctly ... obvious conclusion to anyone reading your question is that you clearly didn't bother to read the what the function actually should do which is lack of research. Being stuck is fine.

Comment: There's a current push to "just downvote and move on" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting?cb=1  - which I don't believe in - a downvote without a reason is useless; so I've given you the courtesy of including the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @CODI Beyond that you still haven't provided expected behavior. We don't see any `.reply` elements in your image so one assumption is there are numerous ones and you want a single value that is related to specific `.reply` OR you want to loop through all of them to find something specific. Objective is not well detailed

Comment: @charlietfl, I updated my question. I was trying to use the generic for each but forgot to remove the [i] I added initially as console.log("commentReferenceId = " + commentReferenceId[i]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective is still a bit fuzzy ( not well explained) but I think this is what you are looking for.

To get the specific value within the same `media` class as the button traverse up to the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) media class container from the button and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the associated input within that container

```
$('.reply').on('click', function() {
    // 'this' is the element instance the event occurred on              
    var commentReferenceId = $(this).closest('.media').find('.commentReferenceId').val();
    console.log("commentReferenceId = " + commentReferenceId);
});
```

Comment: Can you please update the Jquery selector for class to ('.media') otherwise, it returns undefined. So I can accept this answer.

Comment: Opps...missing a dot in `closest('.media')` ...fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the "comments" from the objects with class `commentReferenceId`, you can use `.each` or other methods.

**`.each` method**

```
$('.reply').on('click', function() {
    $('.commentReferenceId').each(function() {
        var commentReferenceId = $(this).val();
        console.log("commentReferenceId = " + commentReferenceId);
    })  
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.commentReferenceId').each(function() {
  var commentReferenceId = $(this).val();
  console.log("commentReferenceId = " + commentReferenceId);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="commentReferenceId" value="test">
<input class="commentReferenceId" value="1">
<input class="commentReferenceId" value="2">
```

Comment: Or .map to get them all in an array (depends on what you want to do with them/when)

Comment: @freedomn-m I agree, but since we can't be sure what the op needs to happen except for the console.log then I just added .each for the example.

Comment: That's why I added the depends clause :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use find() to fix that

```
var medias = document.querySelectorAll('.media')
$('.reply').on('click', function(){

    var commentReferenceId = $(this).find('.commentReferenceId').val();
    console.log("commentReferenceId = " + commentReferenceId);}

);
```